# What is the meaning of the 'x' character suffix?

Tags: meaning, suffixes

The sentence is “2x to 100x speed-ups, typically 4x”.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *x* here is a way to write down the [multiplication symbol **×**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign). It means “times”, as in “speeds-up of 2 to 100 times, typically 4 times”.

The use of *x* to mark the symbol is a remains of the times typewriter were widely used, when the closest approximation to the handwritten multiplication operator was the lowercase letter *x*. Nowadays, all devices can cope with the multiplication sign itself (×), which is part of many post-ASCII character sets, and is of course included in Unicode as U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN.

Answer (score 2):

It is a "multiplier". 2x4=8 (two times four equals eight).